# Reset password Brother 8890DW

Tags: passwords, printer, reset, brother-printer

we have in our office a brother **MFC-8890DW** and we lost the password for user **"admin"** ("access" is the default). How i reset this password (or reset all printer settings)? I  cant do any changes (like ip, name etc...) whitout this pass.

In printer display, i cant access any menu option manually, i think its because appears "common user" on bottom display. I do not know where this user came from.

Thanks.
sorry for my english. iam from brazil.

Comment: I searched for "brother mfc-8890dw reset admin password" and immediately got [this answer](http://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc8890dw_all&faqid=faq00000105_008). Is there something wrong with the information there?

Comment: I try this, if you see in 3º option says "Enter the print server password (The default password is "access") ". To access the printer settings in BRAdmin software, fisrt i need the password.

Comment: There are other methods in the link, including from the front panel.

Comment: Yes, I tried all the methods. As I said, I can not get into the menus (for example in network), it's like I'm not allowed. I will try to do some configuration via USB.

Comment: The front panel reset doesn't appear to need an existing password.

Comment: I made this video: https://streamable.com/u1ixi  . Look, The "menu" option, network in English is inaccessible, as are the other. 
I think it's the "usuário comum" at the botton, common user in English. Very strange.

Comment: Correcting,  The "Rede" option.

Comment: I have watched your video and it is really strange: I found the user manual and according to that there should be an additional option below 8. Under **0.Initial Setup** there should be further options, including **6.** or **7.Reset**, which in turn should have **3.All Settings** and then **1.Reset**.

Answer (score 5):

For most of the Brother printers the console and web mgmt default passwords are the same "**initpass**".

https://help.brother-usa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/152494/~/default-network%2C-firmware-update%2C-and-remote-setup-password

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to connect using telnet

   telnet 192.168.1.10 [repalce with your printer ip]
2. Hit enter key to get the password entering UI and then enter the default telnet password `access`
3. Reset the password using this `SET PASSWORD *YOUR-PASSWORD*`

[image]
[image]

> **Note:** when you change the password from telnet it will change both web and telnet passwords.
>   (in my Brother MFC model)
>   You can clear the password if you leave the password as a blank. Also, it will automatically revert the telnet password back to `access`.

Source[my blog] https://devoptions.blogspot.com/2020/01/brother-printer-password-reset-using.html

Comment: Does it change admin password??

Comment: @MátéJuhász you mean web admin ? Yes it changed.